# How can I add a "Required" attribute to a dynamically-created (C#) element?

Tags: c#, jquery, validation, jquery-validate, required

I want to make some TextBoxes/text inputs "required" so that I can use the Validate jQuery validation plugin.

I tried this:

```
boxPayeeName = new TextBox
{
    CssClass = "finaff-webform-field-input",
    ID = "payeeName",
    Required = true
};
```

...but "Required" is not recognized there; so I tried this:

```
boxPayeeName = new TextBox
{
    CssClass = "finaff-webform-field-input",
    ID = "payeeName"
};
boxPayeeName.Attributes["required"] = "true";
```

I also tried this style of assigning to an attribute, on a similar control:

```
boxRequesterName.Attributes.Add("required", "true");
```

I've got validation via the Validate jQuery plugin set up like this in the jQuery (*.ascx) file:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    . . .
    this.validate();
});
```

...after having set it up like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...but no validation occurs when I exercise the page - I see no validation messages when I leave boxPayeeName and boxRequesterName blank. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue a week back and it was because the "required" attribute  has issues in IE 7-9.

[This is because, according to the post, all versions less than IE 10 are not entirely compliant with HTML 5.](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/301)

If you are using .net, which I'm guessing you are since you're using C#, try using the RequiredFieldValidator feature.