# How can I validate an entire page with the jQuery Validate plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using the jQuery validate plugin is easy in certain situations, such as this, from the official docs, where are [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/):

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
$("#commentForm").validate();
</script>
```

But what if you don't have a "form" per se, but want to apply validation to your entire page?

I tried this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    . . .
    this.validate();
});
```

...but it doesn't seem to work. Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708824/how-can-i-add-a-required-attribute-to-a-dynamically-created-c-element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate the form. So you can validate using :

```
$('#commentForm').validate();
```

OR

```
$('#commentForm').valid();
```

On submit button click event

Comment: You mean this.validate() in the submit button code? I can't do that, because that code is on the server-side, is code-behind, C# code.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I'm reviewing your current questions, and it appears that all of your woes are due to your use of ASP.Net web forms.  To enable the richer client side capabilities that you are looking for, you should consider using plain HTML and Javascript to render your forms client side and make AJAX calls to server side web services.  What you are suffering through is pain that was common place 10 years ago.

Comment: Does that mean I'm ten years younger when I work on this? I don't feel it.

Answer (score 1):

> But what if you don't have a "form" per se, but want to apply validation to your entire page?

The plugin most likely relies on the native (or jquery) [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) functionality. Anytime you are creating a form, you should try to use the `<form>` tag. At least for semantic reasons if nothing else.

Comment: Everything on the page is created server-side, in C#.

Comment: I didn't think that backend validation was part of the question?

Comment: The validation is to take place on the client; the controls are created dynamically with server-side code, though.