# Why is the Validator jQuery plugin not validating with this configuration?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate, ascx

I have the following HTML and jQuery in a Sharepoint .ascx file, trying to validate, for now, just one "required" field (name):

```
<html>
. . .
<form id="firstform">
    <label class="firstblocklabel finaff-webform-field-label">Traveler's name:</label>
    <input class="firstblockinput finaff-webform-field-input" type="text" name="travelername" id="travelername" title="Last Name, First Name, Middle Initial" required/>
    </br>
    . . .
</form>
</html>

<script src="http://bassassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id$=firstform]').validate();
    });
</script>
```

...but it doesn't work; entering into the "travelername" input text an exiting it empty, or adding a value then deleting it and exiting, does not invoke a "Please enter a val" or whatever msg it should be, near the "travelername" text input element.

As you can see, "travelername" is tagged as "required", I'm referencing the validate plugin, and I'm calling validate() in the ready function.

Do I also need to add a reference to a .CSS file?

Note: I also tried this url:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...but that also does not work.

Note that I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708935/how-can-i-validate-an-entire-page-with-the-jquery-validate-plugin), but in this case I'm not using any code-behind, so it should be simpler to get this working.

### UPDATE

An interesting thing happened: On running my page in IE (I know, that was my first mistake, but that's what most of the users have/use), I got an "Error on Page" msg at the bottom of the browser.

To investigate what the error might be, I ran the page in Chrome. There, it showed me right on the page what the error was - the "Requester Name" input text element became focused and a "Please fill out this field" msg appeared next to it. Once I entered something there, all was fine.

So: was the validation plugin working after all?

On looking at my code, what I found was this:

```
boxRequesterName.Attributes.Add("data-group", "1");
boxRequesterName.Attributes.Add("required", "true");
```

I only vaguely recall adding that; apparently it's an HTML5 goodie that Chrome plays well with, whereas my somewhat antiquated version of IE looks askance (or confused) at.

So perhaps this approach is actually a better one for me (adding explicit HTML5 code rather than relying on a plugin).

Comment: `<script src="http://bassassistance ...." ...></script>` use a wrong url (the url to their website is not a CDN), please load the **jquery-validation** plugin from a CDN like `cdnjs`: http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: Okay; it doesn't work with the other URL, either, though. I'll try yours.

Comment: Did you see any error on your browser's console ?

Comment: Nope, no err msgs in the console; it just does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use onfoucusout

```
 $('[id$=firstform]').validate({
          onfocusout: function(element) {
           this.element(element);
        }
 });
```

Added a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/JRNNVag0IL1Hd5GKwEMh?p=preview

Comment: In the Jim Plunker (he played QB for the Raiders back in the day, right), I see:
onblue:true
???

Comment: There is no such `.validate()` option called `onblue` or `onblur`.  Even if there was, as per documentation, you cannot set it to `true` because that is already the default.